# How to point pip to psycopg2 package?

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to install a package which needs `psycopg2` as a dependency, so I installed `psycopg2-binary` using `pip install psycopg2-binary` but when I try to `pip install django-tenant-schemas` I get this error:

```
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:0:
./psycopg/psycopg.h:34:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.

You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages required for the build and try again.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
/home/david/PycharmProjects/clearpath/venv/bin/python -u 
-c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ckbbq00w/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ckbbq00w/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install
--record /tmp/pip-record-pi6j7x5l/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed
--compile
--install-headers /home/david/PycharmProjects/clearpath/venv/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

When I go into my projects (using PyCharm) repo settings I can see psycopg2-binary is installed. I assume this has something to do with the PATH but I can't seem to figure out how to solve the issue.

`which psql`: /usr/bin/psql

`which pg_config`: /usr/bin/pg_config

I am not comfortable doing much in the Environment variables as I really don't want to break something.

Comment: Do you have `gcc` installed?

Comment: Yes. `gcc --version`: gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

Comment: Ahh! I will undelete. Thank you very much for notifying me of this.

Comment: It is undeleted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you try to install pscopg2, and it may cause problem if psycopg2-binary is already installed

Here are your logs on several lines:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
/home/david/PycharmProjects/clearpath/venv/bin/python -u 
-c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ckbbq00w/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ckbbq00w/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install
--record /tmp/pip-record-pi6j7x5l/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed
--compile
--install-headers /home/david/PycharmProjects/clearpath/venv/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

> I would try to uninstall `psycopg2-binary` and then reinstall `django-tenant-schemas`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be a bad install of libpq-fe-h that was fixed using a reinstall. Question was solved [here](http://Was%20solved%20[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961043/how-to-install-libpq-fe-h?noredirect=1#comment104177342_58961043))

Answer (score 0):

`psycopg2` and `psycopg2-binary` are technically two separate packages, even though they provide exactly the same functionality. They are just bundled differently.

It's hacky, but you can pip install `psycopg2-binary` and then also convince pip that you actually installed `psycopg2`. To do that, go to `site-packages` of your environment, and create `psycopg2-2.9.9.dist-info/METADATA` file. The file can be empty.

If you then try to run `pip install psycopg2` (or indirectly via another dependency), pip will tell you that `Requirement already satisfied`.