# How to install libpq-fe.h?

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, pip

I cannot figure this out for the life of me.

When I `pip install django-tenant-schemas` it tries to install the dependency `psycopg2` which requires the Python headers and gcc. I have all this installed and still keep getting this error!

```
./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
```

So to install `libpq-fe-h` I need to `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`..

..which returns..

```
libpq-dev is already the newest version (10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).
```

Then when I `sudo find / libpq-fe.h` it doesn't seem to be in my OS.

I am lost at this point. If anyone can help I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Try to do a reinstall: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpq-dev`

Comment: Oh my lord! I have tried everything and nothing has worked! I reinstallled everything but this! So frustrating! thank you!

Comment: I had the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04, and this simple command saved my day.

Comment: I can confirm that this is still the case for my Ubuntu 20.04 VM when trying to install `psycopg2` and this command saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

For some reason, the file is missing on the system.

As you're using `apt-get`, the system is `dpkg` based, presumably Debian or it's derivative. You can try the [Ubuntu's package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search) to get which package contains a file with name *ending in* `libpq-fe.h`.

[I found the package is `libpq-dev` and file's absolute path is `/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libpq-fe.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=disco&arch=any).

---

FWIW, on a `dpkg` based system, you can check which package gives a file if you know the file's absolute path:

```
% dpkg -S /usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h
libpq-dev: /usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h
```

Also, unlike `find`, `locate` keeps a cache of found files (`mlocate.db`) that is created everyday via `cron`; so if the file happens to be removed after the last run, you can run `locate libfq-fe.h` to get the absolute path to the file without needing to check the Ubuntu package search online.

---

So the package is `libpq-dev`. Now, reinstalling it will get everything to the default state i.e. all relevant files will be copied to the right places. As it is only a library package, no user/system level configurations will be overridden (and `dpkg` will prompt you for action for any package that does that).

To reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpq-dev
```

Comment: Yup. Re-installing `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpq-dev` worked for me to the same problem, too! Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what ever the h*ll happened to my new VM, but just the reinstall command did it for me.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I realized it was trying to use the deprecated setup.py so I installed wheel (`pip install wheel`) and that sorted it all out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that indicates the path of your library `/user/pgsql-11/lib`

**Source:** The 3rd point of build prerequisites at https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#build-prerequisites

Comment: Only if it returns an unexpected version number - which was not my case.

Answer (score 2):

Well after installing these libraries
`sudo dnf install python-virtualenv openssl-devel gcc libffi-devel libxslt-devel` issue was not gone.

I used `mlocate` to find where `libpq-fe.h` file is located. On my system (Fedora 32) it was located at `/usr/pgsql-10/include/libpq-fe.h`

```sh
yum install mlocate
sudo updateb
locate libpq-fe.h
```

After all added this line to `~/.bash_profile`

```sh
nano ~/.bash_profile
export PATH=/usr/pgsql-10/bin/:$PATH
```

Works fine, I can easily install `psycopg2` without any trouble.

Comment: I got 
`locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory`

Comment: You have to install mlocate